# Multiple HTML pages & Pagination

Tags: php, html, css

Okay, so currently I'm creating a website from scratch for my small online shop and am stuck on where to even begin when it comes to my Products page. Currently, I have 1 page that displays all 50 of my products. I plan on expanding my products and do not want someone to be scrolling down the whole page. I would like to add multiple pages that you can click through and I believe I can accomplish this through Pagination. Now, this is the part where I get confused : say I only want 25 products to be displayed per page and I add a new item to the first page - how do items get 'bumped' to the page 2, 3 etc.? I would imagine there is some function to accomplish this, but the only way I can think of is doing this the brute force way of manually moving a product out of one page and onto another. Any suggestions??

Currently, my website is coded in all HTML / CSS and I currently just learned how to use PHP to mass edit certain areas of the website -- I am in the learning stages! Any suggestions would help. Thanks!

Comment: Have  you looked at pagination tutorials?

Comment: If you had all the products hardcode in a single page, then you can just use javascript to fake the pagination, otherwise you'll have to let the server spit out the pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the help of a database to paginate your products in sets.

Basically, the database will have a "Products" table, each row in the table will represent a single product.  You will use PHP to ask the database to retrieve the first/next N rows and then write out the appropriate HTML around each returned row to create a list of products.

There are lots of [tutorials on the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=pagination%20php&oq=pagination%20php) to help you learn while you practice.  Good luck!

Comment: Ohh, I didn't realize I had to utilize the database for this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that on static HTML web-site.

You need server-side script (e.g. PHP script) for splitting your product list by pages. By the way, you should store your data in DB and it should be done on the DB-side to not overhead your PHP side.